# How can I set up the bootstrapper package for Windows Installer 4.5 for a ClickOnce application?

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce

From `Prerequisites` on the `Publish` tab, I selected the option to `Download prerequisites from the same location as my application`.

I got an error while publishing which gave me the following instruction:

> To enable 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my
>   application' in the Prerequisites dialog box, you must download file
>   'WindowsInstaller4_5\Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU' for item 'Windows
>   Installer 4.5' to your local machine. For more information, see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018

The knowledge base article says to open the `Package.xml` file in the language folder (`en`) within `WindowsInstaller4_5` and then

> Locate the Name element that contains http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink,
>   and copy the URL. Include the LinkID portion

But the `package.xml` file does not have any entry with `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink`! Other bootstrapper folders have this entry in the package.xml file, but not `WindowsInstaller4_5`

Has anybody else succeeded at adding the Windows Installer 4.5 package? How did you succeed?

I am using VS2015 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is explicitly mentioned in the linked MSDN article:

> **Note**
> If no Name element contains `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink`, open the Product.xml file in the root folder for the prerequisite and locate the fwlink string.

It is there, bottom of the file.  Beware that the message you got is a bit misleading, there are a total of *eight* installers you have to download to your machine.  Which one the user will actually use depends on his Windows version.

I would very strongly recommend that you do **not** do this.  To the user it just doesn't make any difference if he downloads the installer from the Microsoft server or from yours.  Except for one gritty detail, if he actually *needs* the installer then he's not keeping his machine updated with Windows Update.

That's pretty unlikely these days, thank heavens, but if you encounter such a user then he'll be, how do I say this gracefully..., *a major pain in your rear end*.  He'll expect *you* to provide support when there is any issue getting this installer deployed since it was your machine that provided it.  And necessarily so, he can't get support from Microsoft.  Realistically you cannot provide such support either, you have no idea what shape the machine is in.

Comment: As you said, is highly recommended check 'Download prerequisites from the component vendor's web site'. But the option 'Download prerequisites from the same location as my application' is recommended to disconnected environments.

Comment: Hmm, I have no real idea how anybody ever gets to the ClickOnce publish URL on a disconnected machine.

Comment: Not using ClickOnce

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem with VS2015 in Windows 7.
Finally I found the solution downloading the install packages for the Windows Installer 4.5 and copying them into next path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\WindowsInstaller4_5".
After this, Setup project compiling worked.

It would be necessary to copy all versions of the Windows Installer 4.5 as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Beside the OS (I am on win 8.1 on my deverloper machine), i have almost the same scenario like you.

Your issue sounds like something (someone) messed up your product.xml-file.

Below you find the original content of said file, which is working for me perfectly.

**Note**

> Before you edit the file, make sure you back up the original one!
>
> **Rootfolder** -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages\WindowsInstaller4_5

**Filecontent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Windows Installer 4.5 VS Bootstrapper : product.xml : Language neutral information -->
<Product
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper"
    ProductCode="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5">
  <!-- The package does not contain an IncludesProduct element for Windows Installer 3.1. -->
  <!-- This ommision is by design in order to achive a specific sequencing of bootstrapper packages -->
  <!-- to reduce the number of potential reboots under certain conditions. -->

  <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe" HomeSite="Msi45XPx86exe"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe" HomeSite="Msi45UpdateXPx86exe"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe" HomeSite="Msi452K3x86exe"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe" HomeSite="Msi45Update2K3x86exe"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe" HomeSite="Msi45XP2K3x64exe"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe" HomeSite="Msi45UpdateXP2K3x64exe"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU" HomeSite="Msi45Vistax86msu"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
    <PackageFile Name="Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU" HomeSite="Msi45Vistax64msu"
                 PublicKey="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"/>
  </PackageFiles>

  <InstallChecks>
    <FileCheck Property="VersionMsiDll" FileName="msi.dll" SearchPath="System32" SpecialFolder="WindowsFolder" />
  </InstallChecks>
  <!-- Defines how to invoke the setup for the Windows installer 4.5 redist -->
  <Commands Reboot="Immediate">
    <!-- Defines installation command for:
                  Windows XP Service Pack 2 and later
                  on x86 platform -->
    <Command PackageFile="WindowsXP-KB942288-v3-x86.exe"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="3327000"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsi" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" />
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.1.2" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <!-- Defer reboot until MSI 4.5 update below -->
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="Success"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <Command PackageFile="WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="1506160"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsiDll" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5.6001.22299" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" />
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.1.2" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <!-- Defines installation command for:
                  Windows 2003 Service Pack 1 or later
                  on x86 platform -->
    <Command PackageFile="WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x86.exe"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="3071512"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsi" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.2.0"/>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="6.0"/>
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <!-- Defer reboot until MSI 4.5 update below -->
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="Success"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <Command PackageFile="WindowsServer2003-KB958655-v2-x86-ENU.exe"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="1502584"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsiDll" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5.6001.22299" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.2.0"/>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="6.0"/>
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <!-- Defines installation command for:
                  Windows XP Service Pack 2 and later
                  Windows 2003 Service Pack 1 or later
                  on x64 platform -->
    <Command PackageFile="WindowsServer2003-KB942288-v4-x64.exe"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="4691480"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsi" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="6.0"/>
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.1.2" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <!-- Defer reboot until MSI 4.5 update below -->
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="Success"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <Command PackageFile="WindowsServer2003.WindowsXP-KB958655-v2-x64-ENU.exe"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="2904952"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsiDll" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5.6001.22299" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="6.0"/>
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="5.1.2" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionEqualTo" Value="5.2.0" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <!-- Defines installation command for:
                  Vista RTM and later
                  Windows Server 2008 RTM and later
                  on x86 platform -->
    <Command PackageFile="Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x86.MSU"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="1960465"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsiDll" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5.6001.22308" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="Intel" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.0" />
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>

    <!-- Defines installation command for:
                  Vista RTM and later
                  Windows Server 2008 RTM and later
                  on x64 platform -->
    <Command PackageFile="Windows6.0-KB958655-v2-x64.MSU"
             Arguments= "/quiet /norestart"
             EstimatedInstalledBytes="3342348"
             EstimatedInstallSeconds="120" >
      <InstallConditions>
        <BypassIf Property="VersionMsiDll" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="4.5.6001.22308" />
        <BypassIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueNotEqualTo" Value="amd64" />
        <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.0" />
        <FailIf Property="Version9x" Compare="ValueExists" String="InvalidPlatform"/>
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired"/>
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success"/>
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="true" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>

  <!-- Defines Homesite locations for each of the downloads -->
  <Strings>
    <String Name="Msi45XPx86exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=118633</String>
    <String Name="Msi45UpdateXPx86exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161053</String>
    <String Name="Msi452K3x86exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=119115</String>
    <String Name="Msi45Update2K3x86exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161054</String>
    <String Name="Msi45XP2K3x64exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=118636</String>
    <String Name="Msi45UpdateXP2K3x64exe">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161055</String>
    <String Name="Msi45Vistax86msu">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161056</String>
    <String Name="Msi45Vistax64msu">http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=161057</String>
  </Strings>
</Product>
```